# Filter a criteria query by a subquery attribute

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

I'm trying to implement a criteria a bit complex.
My first query was this.

```
SELECT * FROM pin AS activepin
WHERE activepin.pin_nbr NOT IN 
( 
 SELECT p.pin_nbr 
 FROM pin AS p 
 GROUP BY p.pin_nbr,p.is_active 
 HAVING p.is_active = 0 
 AND count(*) =( 
    SELECT count(*) 
    FROM pin 
    WHERE pin_nbr = p.pin_nbr 
    GROUP BY pin_nbr)
 );
```

so, in order to convert having to where clause (i think that having and criteria are not good friends xD) i converted it in this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM pin AS activePin
WHERE activePin.pin_nbr NOT IN (
    SELECT innerQuery2.pin_nbr
    FROM(
        SELECT p.pin_nbr,
               p.is_active,
               count(*) AS quantity
        FROM pin p
        GROUP BY p.pin_nbr,
                 p.is_active) AS innerQuery2
     WHERE innerQuery2.is_active = 0
     AND innerQuery2.quantity =(
         SELECT count(*)
         FROM pin
         WHERE pin_nbr = innerQuery2.pin_nbr
         GROUP BY pin_nbr
         )
 );
```

and then i did this criteria

```
        DetachedCriteria innerQuery3 = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Pin.class, "innerQuery3")
                .setProjection(Projections.rowCount())
                .setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("innerQuery3.pinNbr"))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("innerQuery2.pinNbr", "pinNbr"));

        DetachedCriteria innerQuery2 = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Pin.class, "innerQuery2")
                .setProjection(Projections.rowCount())
                .setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("innerQuery2.pinNbr"))
                .setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("innerQuery2.active"))
                .add(Subqueries.eq(Projections.rowCount(), innerQuery3))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("innerQuery2.pinNbr", "pinNbr"));

        DetachedCriteria innerQuery1 = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Pin.class, "innerQuery1")
                .setProjection(Projections.property("innerQuery2.pinNbr"))
                .add(Subqueries.exists(innerQuery2))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("innerQuery2.active", false));

        criteria.add(Subqueries.propertyNotIn("pinNbr", innerQuery1));
```

which throw me the following Exception

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: null

I think this happens because i'm adding a Restrictions by a subquery value (i mind, at innerQuery1 i want to filter by a innerQuery2 value, that is because i want to filter after group clause).

Any clue of how this can be done? i've been researching how to filter by a  subquery value outside that subquery with no results.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT p.pin_nbr 
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.is_active = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as sum_active
       count(*) as total
FROM pin AS p 
GROUP BY p.pin_nbr
HAVING total!=sum_active
```

let's rewrite the SQL query first. As far as I understand you need all pin_nbr where all items are active.

You can use `Projections.sqlProjection()` for the expression above. For the query you add HAVING check on java side or place this in a subquery.

Comment: men you rock! it was to much easier make criteria from that query, and at the end i've avoid HAVING clause and check on java for the active pins.

By the way, your guess was correct, i need all pin_nbr where all items are active.